# ModelData interface gxt

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gxt

I'm implementing a server-client data transfering in gxt.
So, I have a Bean class and a class that extends BeanModelMarker.
Then I fill my bean's fields with data from DB on server.
Then I use GWT RPC

Should I use gxt beanmodelfactory to convert my beants to model data and to fill my grid? Where and when should I use it?

Comment: I think this is all best explained in http://www.sencha.com/blog/preview-java-bean-support-with-ext-gwt/
Even though it says "preview" in the article what's covered is now standard (as the article is from 2008).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the BeanModelReader in the loader:

```
BeanModelReader reader = new BeanModelReader();
ListLoader<ListLoadResult<ModelData>>loader = new BaseListLoader<ListLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy,reader);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use it in the success call in your RPC event so (i am gonna assume your pojo is called Bean)

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Bean pojo) {
  BeanModelFactory factory = BeanModelLookup.get().getFactory(Bean.class);
  BeanModel bean = factory.createModel(pojo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check out the `com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BeanModelReader` - This should help you to get the Data into your grid.

Take a look at following example to see what Reader, Loader, Proxy and Store are doing:

http://www.sencha.com/examples/pages/grid/beanmodel.html